# Embedded images not showing in email from Javamail html template

Tags: java, html, jakarta-mail

I have successfully followed tutorials of how to embed images into HTML with javamail. However i am now trying to read from a template html file and then embed images into this before sending.

I am sure that the code is right for the embedding images as when i use:

```
bodyPart.setContent("<html><body><h2>A title</h2>Some text in here<br/>" +
               "<img src=\"cid:the-img-1\"/><br/> some more text<img src=\"cid:the-img-1\"/></body></html>", "text/html");
```

The images display fine. However when i read from a file using:

```
readHTMLToString reader = new readHTMLToString();
String str = reader.readHTML();  
bodyPart.setContent(str, "text/html");
```

The images do not show up when the email sends.

My code for reading the html to string is as follows:

```
public class readHTMLToString {
static String finalFile;

public static String readHTML() throws IOException{

//intilize an InputStream
    File htmlfile = new File("C:/temp/basictest.html");
    System.out.println(htmlfile.exists());
try {
  FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(htmlfile);

  byte[] buffer= new byte[(int)htmlfile.length()];
new DataInputStream(fin).readFully(buffer);
    fin.close();
    String s = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    finalFile = s;
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
  System.out.println("File not found" + e);
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
  System.out.println("Exception while reading the file " + ioe);
}
return finalFile;
  }
}
```

My complete class for sending the email is as follows:

```
package com.bcs.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class SendEmail {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final String username = "usernamehere@gmail.com";
    final String password = "passwordhere";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");


    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("recepientemailhere"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

        //SET MESSAGE AS HTML
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");  

        // Create bodypart.  
        BodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  

        // Create the HTML with link to image CID.  
        // Prefix the link with "cid:". 

        //bodyPart.setContent("<html><body><h2>A title</h2>Some text in here<br/>" +
              // "<img src=\"cid:the-img-1\"/><br/> some more text<img src=\"cid:the-img-1\"/></body></html>", "text/html");
        readHTMLToString reader = new readHTMLToString();
        String str = reader.readHTML();  

        // Set the MIME-type to HTML.  
        bodyPart.setContent(str, "text/html");  

        // Add the HTML bodypart to the multipart.  
        multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);  

        // Create another bodypart to include the image attachment.  
        BodyPart imgPart = new MimeBodyPart();  

        // Read image from file system.  
        DataSource ds = new FileDataSource("C:\\temp\\dice.png");  
        imgPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));  

        // Set the content-ID of the image attachment.  
        // Enclose the image CID with the lesser and greater signs. 
        imgPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
        imgPart.setHeader("Content-ID","the-img-1");
        //bodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image_cid>");  

        // Add image attachment to multipart.  
        multipart.addBodyPart(imgPart);  

        // Add multipart content to message.  
        message.setContent(multipart);  



        //message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
        //  + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

Ive read through numerous answers about this but really not sure why this is happening. I thought it was because of an issue with my html file however i created a very basic one using the same content as the initial setContent code above and the pictures dont appear in this basic example.

Something to do with reading into a byte array?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way email clients interpret HTML code is different from writing to HTML template file. But one thing you could try for sure is once you get the template, copy the byte array of the image to the  src attribute. You could try with inline images as browser inteprets src attribute and make another request to get the data.

Gives you a lot more insight in to the concept.[Inline Images in HTML](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply however i am not entirely sure that i fully understand you answer. To clarify, if i am simply reading the text from the html file into a string why would it be interpreted differently? Could you possible give an example regarding copying the byte array of the image to the src attribute. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to make sure that the data in the file is actually encoded in UTF-8 and not in the default encoding for your computer.  If you test this with all ASCII text, it shouldn't matter.

Assuming you have the same text in the file that you have in the string in the sample code above, you can compare the two cases (string, file) to see how the messages JavaMail would send differ by using message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt")); just before or in place of the Transport.send call.

Comment: Hello Bill thanks for your suggestion. The encoding in the html template is indeed UTF-8. When i wrote the message to .txt the html appears to be identical but with the base64 code of the image after it and the message properties before it followed by: ` ------=_Part_0_21357269.1334981436511
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.  Just to check, you're using the same code to construct the message in both cases, with the **only** difference being how you set the content for the main message body part, right?  It might be helpful if you could post both versions of the msg.txt file.